# Convert flattened json into nested json

Tags: json, go

Currently I'm using the following code to convert nested json into flattened json:

```
import (
    "fmt"

    "github.com/nytlabs/gojsonexplode"
)
func main() {
    input := `{"person":{"name":"Joe", "address":{"street":"123 Main St."}}}`
    out, err := gojsonexplode.Explodejsonstr(input, ".")
    if err != nil {
        // handle error
    }
    fmt.Println(out)
}
```

This is the output: `{"person.address.street":"123 Main St.","person.name":"Joe"}`

After some processing, now I want to restore this data into normal nested json, but I'm unable to do so.

My closest guess is usage of nested maps, but I don't know how to create nested map with N levels.

EDIT: Reason why I need this: I'm storing data in Redis, and if I store json into Redis then I can't search for keys, that's why I convert keys into `key1:key2:key3: some_value`

Comment: Why aren't you just processing the JSON in its unnested form? Without any additional information, that seems like an odd conversion to do.

Comment: Because I need to store it into Redis, and if I store the json into Redis I can't search for specific keys.
That's I why convert the keys into this key1:key2:key3:value etc. But then at some point I need it in json again.

Comment: That makes sense.  Have you attempted to write a reversal function for the gojsonexplode package?

Comment: I'm not good enough with Go to reverse gojsonexplode package. I attempted it but I failed

Comment: If size of the data isn't a problem you could keep a copy of the nested json inside the flattened one. https://play.golang.org/p/kM4UyUA0Ry

Comment: Here's a more naive quick and dirty solution https://goplay.space/#_RIaXWDcVt

Comment: @reticentroot I used Person only as an example (taken from gojsonexplode package). Data is not fixed, it can have various keys and various nesting levels.

Comment: @Alen Sounds like a good time to write a reverse for gojsonexplode then :-) you may not know Go well enough now, but you'll know it a lot better if you write that function.  You can always write the function the best you can and when you get stuck ask the appropriate questions/errors on SOF. In that way you solve your original question and learn some more Go.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to "unflatten" the data you need to split each of the keys at the dot and create nested objects. [Here is an example](https://play.golang.org/p/4juOff38ea) with your data on the Go Playground.

```
func unflatten(flat map[string]interface{}) (map[string]interface{}, error) {
    unflat := map[string]interface{}{}

    for key, value := range flat {
        keyParts := strings.Split(key, ".")

        // Walk the keys until we get to a leaf node.
        m := unflat
        for i, k := range keyParts[:len(keyParts)-1] {
            v, exists := m[k]
            if !exists {
                newMap := map[string]interface{}{}
                m[k] = newMap
                m = newMap
                continue
            }   

            innerMap, ok := v.(map[string]interface{})
            if !ok {
                return nil, fmt.Errorf("key=%v is not an object", strings.Join(keyParts[0:i+1], "."))
            }   
            m = innerMap
        }   

        leafKey := keyParts[len(keyParts)-1]
        if _, exists := m[leafKey]; exists {
            return nil, fmt.Errorf("key=%v already exists", key)
        }   
        m[keyParts[len(keyParts)-1]] = value
    }   

    return unflat, nil 
}
```

Comment: Man, you are absolutely awesome. Thank you 1000 times

Comment: Note that the flattened version is ambiguous. You cannot distinguish `["x"]` from `{"0":"x"}`, or `{"x":{"y":"z"}}` from `{"x.y":"z"}`. So be careful with your input.

Answer (score -1):

[json.MarshalIndent](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#MarshalIndent) is your friend.

```
j, err := json.MarshalIndent(x, "", "\t")
if err != nil {
    log.Println(err)
}
log.Println(string(j))
```

It will print your data (x) in indented manner.

Comment: Sorry but this doesn't solve my problem, I'm trying to convert key1:key2: some_value into nested json: {"key1": {"key2": "some_value"}}